# OpenCV Assertion failed size.width>0 && size.height>0

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

escribí este código:

```
import cv2

imagen = cv2.imread('grillos.jpg')

cv2.imshow('Imagen', imagen)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cadena/Documentos/Python Programas/contador grillos/grillos.py", line 5, in <module>
  cv2.imshow('Img', imagen)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

De antemano muchas gracias :D por su ayuda :) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error viene por que cv2.imread no puede leer la imagen directamente, según la recomendación de la documentación.

te pongo el ejemplo de la documentacion.

import cv2

path = r'C:\Users\Rajnish\Desktop\geeksforgeeks.png'

img = cv2.imread(path)

Comment: Ya realice la modificación, pero me sigue arrojando exactamente el mismo error en el código 5 X_x sin embargo agradezco bastante tu respuesta, fuiste el unico en responderme :p